# Implementing LowerHex to preserve format options

Tags: rust

Let's say I have a type `Point` whose coordinates I want to format in hex. I can do this:

```rust
use std::fmt;

struct Point {
    x : i32,
    y : i32
}

impl fmt::LowerHex for Point {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "(x=")?;
        fmt::LowerHex::fmt(&self.x, f)?;
        write!(f, ", y=")?;
        fmt::LowerHex::fmt(&self.y, f)?;
        write!(f, ")")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let p = Point { x : 100, y : 200 };
    println!("Point is {0:x} or {0:#06x}", p);
}
```

That prints, as desired:

```
Point is (x=64, y=c8) or (x=0x0064, y=0x00c8)
```

Is this the best way of implementing `LowerHex` for `Point`?

And, if I want to them implement `UpperHex` as well, do I just have to basically duplicate all of this logic again?

Comment: Agree, it's weird that derive macros aren't available for these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the lack of derive macros for `LowerHex` and `UpperHex`, there is a formatting string that automatically applies hexadecimal printing to the struct's members as long as the struct implements `Debug`. Placing a question mark after the "hexadecimal x" means that the object should be debug-printed, but its integer members should be printed in hexadecimal.

Then, if you manually implement `Debug` to get the basic format that you want, using the provided `fmt::Formatter` to write the object's fields, things will "just work".

```rust
use std::fmt;

struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl fmt::Debug for Point {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        f.write_str("(x=")?;
        self.x.fmt(f)?;
        f.write_str(", y=")?;
        self.y.fmt(f)?;
        f.write_str(")")?;

        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let p = Point { x: 100, y: 200 };
    println!("{:?}", p);
    println!("{:x?}", p);
    println!("{:#06x?}", p);
    println!("{:#06X?}", p);
}
```

This prints the desired

```
(x=100, y=200)
(x=64, y=c8)
(x=0x0064, y=0x00c8)
(x=0x0064, y=0x00C8)
```

Comment: Weird that you can do this for `Debug` but not `Display`? All the other formatting flags are propagated (like alignment, etc.), just... not hex? And `x?` works but not `b?`